# GFCI outlet with led light not on but have power

Tags: gfci

I have a new GFCI outlet with the LED light not on.  But the outlet has power and the load outlet also has power.  The test button works and you can reset the GFCI, but no LED light comes on. What can be wrong?

Comment: If you trip the GFCI, does the light come on?

Answer (score -1):

The light should only come on when the GFCI is tripped in most outlets.  There are GFCI outlet testers available; big box home stores carry them.  If the light doesn't come on when the outlet is tripped *and* the outlet tests correctly, it's probably the outlet.  Replacing the outlet would be the way forward to fix that.  The GFCI tester may show other problems which could cause unexpected behavior and should be fixed.

Comment: All of my GFCI outlets have an LED on to indicate they are working. I would assume in this case the outlet is wired wrong, either swapped line and load or swapped hot and nuetral